# Redirection in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, redirect

I want to use redirect in symfony to generate a url and at the same time I want to make a variable 'levels', accessible in the twig template but it does not seem to be working for me.
here is the code:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('show_admin_panel'), array('levels' => $levels));
```

I got this error: The HTTP status code "1" is not valid.

and if I use this:

`return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('show_admin_panel', array('levels' => $levels) ) );`

I get this error:  Variable "levels" does not exist in AUIAraBundle:Admin:admin_panel.html.twig at line 10

this is the code in the twig template:

```
 {% for level in levels %}
    <a href="{{ path('list_books',{'level_id': level.id}) }}"><li>{{level.letter}}</li></a>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: The HTTP status code "1" is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to query that variable 'level' in the action that redirects, just do:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('show_admin_panel'));
```

Then in your controller linked to your 'show_admin_panel', make sure query that variable and pass it to the render method

```
//$level = something;
return $this->render('AUIAraBundle:Admin:admin_panel.html.twig',
            array(
                'levels' => $levels
                )
            );
    }
```

Comment: no its not working: i get now this error: Variable "levels" does not exist in AUIAraBundle:Admin:admin_panel.html.twig at line 10

Comment: but when you use render instead of redirect, you obviously don't redirect the user

Comment: I used your code but I don't get anything in the level variable. that the code in the adminpanelAction: $levels = $request->get('levels');
  return $this->render('AUIAraBundle:Admin:admin_panel.html.twig',
   array(
     'levels' => $levels
    )
  );

Comment: This solution is incorrect - the array of values passed as the second param to generateUrl() is for parameters that are embedded within the url and come into the controller method as function parameters

Comment: ok ok. I got you and I got how that redirection really works. thanks a lot, it is working now and I found an even better solution based on you comment.

Comment: @redbirdo, you right if the levels variable is in the url definition, otherwise the generateUrl method will generate somthing like ?levels=xxx, this kind of variable is not injected in the action method

Comment: @VBee Sorry, I wasn't aware of that - where is that documented? (I can only find it on the comment of UrlGeneratorInterface::generate()). As levels is an array of objects would it come through as a serialised array? Would it need to be converted before passing to twig?